# Should I edit answers to fix deprecation?

Tags: support, edits

So let's say there was an answer that had a deprecated issue. For example, `getResources().getDrawable()` in Android is deprecated, so should I edit it to replace it with the new one (`ContextCompat.getDrawable`)? Or should I leave it as is?

Comment: **You should leave it**. Consider adding your *own* answer, referring to the previous, explaining why you have added it.

Comment: @Paulie_D but what if it was **accepted**? Most people will pay attention to the accepted answer, not the lowest one on the lsit

Comment: That happens. The acceptance just means that the OP found it the most useful..not that it's the most recent *right* answer.

Comment: Of course if you wrote the answer, feel free to expand on it rather than writing a new answer.

Comment: Well, don't exclude the possibility that your new answer can be accepted.  The OP might well come back, see the better solution and like it enough to consider using it as well.  Very easy for him to change the accepted solution.  Doesn't always happen but certainly *is* the way SO is supposed to work.